# Is there a function for getting a list of installed NPM dependencies in dependency order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to traverse each directory (that has `package.json`) in a specific `node_modules` directory from a NPM package in the file system, but I need to do that based on the dependency (ascending) order, not name ascending order or unordered. E.g.:

```
// 'y' relies on 'x', so 'x' appears first in the array
[
    'x',
    'y',
]
```

I thought of synchronously invoking a child process to use something like `npm ll`, but there are some issues:

- I'll have to filter text. A `output.replace(/.../g, '')` can easily solve that, but it looks inconvenient.
- `npm ll` doesn't list all installed packages (e.g. indirect dependencies).

Is there a function for getting something like `['foo-dependency', 'bar-dependency']` for direct and indirect packages and in dependency ascending order?

I can also read `package-lock.json`, but I don't think it has an array with the installed dependencies in the desired order. Although I'm not sure whether the `"node_modules/k"` keys are in dependency order, I don't want to rely on them because I'll use `JSON.parse` and the key order is indeterministic.

---

According to comments here, `package-lock.json` should have the fields at `"packages"` ordered by ascending dependency order, but that's not the case. Here is an example:

- [sample-package-lock.json](https://gist.github.com/hydroper/41d7ab07b25d717953f1d0a0ad14c02a)
- [sample-package.json](https://gist.github.com/hydroper/f87a6b477bb6c6e3ea28bfa3bca76e18)

Do the following:

- Search for `node_modules/ts-node` in the sample-package-lock.json and look at its line number. It has a non-dev dependency `v8-compile-cache-lib`.
- Search for `node_modules/v8-compile-cache-lib` in the sample-package-lock.json and look at its line number.

You can see that `v8-compile-cache-lib` appears after `ts-node`. It should appear first. So looking at `package-lock.json` is not a solution.

Comment: Can't you parse your `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: @vighnesh153 That could work, but I'm not sure where in `package-lock.json` I can get a flat array as described above in the dependency order...

Comment: @vighnesh153 I can see that it has `node_modules/*` keys, but are they in the dependency order? I'm a bit unsure. I'd rather get an array over a plain object too.

Comment: AFAIK, `package-lock.json` will have all dependencies in ascending order unless edited manually.

Comment: Why would this be necessary? What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: @vighnesh153 This can be problematic anyway since `JSON.parse` may alter the key order.

Comment: @Pointy I'm creating a TypeScript to SWF compiler for Adobe AIR, which will target ActionScript bytecode, not ActionScript source.

Comment: If you use `Object.keys` to read the keys, it will preserve the order of keys as defined in the JSON string.

Comment: @vighnesh153 Looking at `package-lock.json` does not work. Look at the end of the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as "dependency order", since dependencies might be circular. And even for non-circular dependencies, you'd have a DAG, and would need any topological order

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand what is DAG at all, but I guess I wanted to mean indeed _any_ topological order. I ended up not needing this for a goal-specific reason, but I'll leave the question open.